# IQuerable with Linq to find string part in datetime

Tags: c#, sql, linq

What I want to do is allow the user to search for *part of the date* that is shown in the result set.

table of results

```
ID  | Name | Date  
1     Bob    31 August 2018  
2     Bill   29 June 2000  
31    Foo    1 June 2005
```

There is a search box and if the user searches for say "31", I need to then construct an IQuerable<> with Linq and Entity framework 6

```
var searchValue = "31"

var data = IQuerable<T>

data.Where(x => x.Date.ToString("D").Contains(searchValue)
                || x.Id.Contains(searchValue)
                || x.Name.Contains(searchValue)).Take(x).Skip(Y)
```

The result should be

```
ID  | Name | Date  
1     Bob    31 August 2018  
31    Foo    1 June 2005
```

But the results are always null.

The table I am searching has about 500,000 records. 
It works across everything apart from the date.

Comment: Please post syntactically complete code for us to work with, this does not compile, what is `searchValue`, what is `data`, your parenthesis do not match, etc.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? Entity Framework Core? LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: String representations of DateTime are culture specific. You should use `ToString(String, IFormatProvider)` overload.

Comment: What a minimal example looks like -->  https://dotnetfiddle.net/eFKR8A

Comment: Why use such code at all? If you want to check for a specific month, just check for a specific month with the [DateTime.Month](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.month%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property

Comment: Thanks, Freggar, so from your example it should work.

Comment: @TheAlbear why don't you perform a simple `Where(x=>x.Date.month==4)`? Why are you converting to a string that depends on the user's locale?

Comment: @TheAlbear why the `sql` tag? LINQ to Objects isn't the same as LINQ to an ORM. Searching by first converting to text will be slow and produce wrong results. Searching for months in a date field in the database won't produce bad results but it won't be fast either. Using a *calendar table* will be both fast and correct

Comment: Don't think I have explained what I was trying to do properly, I have rewritten the question to hopefully make more sense.

Comment: @TheAlbear But you haven't given us what you are using the IQueryable against. Entity Framework, Entity Framework Core, LINQ-to-SQL, ... I can give you a response for one IQueryable type that wont't work for *your* IQueryable.

Comment: This feature is flawed, if I search for "1" it will return all days from "01". "10-19", "21","31", January and everything between  "999-2000", etc. Dates are ranges also you can use the day/month/year part od the date with better results

Comment: It's a generic search box, so yes any data from the whole row where there is matching substring will be returned. The issue is not the function but how to get the date information into something that can be searched.

Answer (score 1):

Check this tested example replace date object with your object value and pass a value in contains which you need to check.

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = new DateTime[] { new DateTime(2018, 09, 01), new DateTime(2018, 08, 11) };
            var query = data.Where(x => x.Date.ToString("D").Contains("Aug"));
            foreach (var dat in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dat);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Let me know if it works for you.